# Django returns variable name not value in request.POST.get()

Tags: django, django-templates

I define a `<select/>` in my django template as follows

```
{% get_selected_item as selected_item %}
<select name="item_selected" id="item_selected">
    {% for item in items %}
        <option value=item{% if selected_item == item %} selected{% endif %}>{{ item }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

But when I examine the result of 
`request.POST.getlist('item_selected')` or `request.POST.get('item_selected')`
the result is the string 'item', not the string value of the selected item.

The items are not part of a model but are provided in a session variable.

Comment: Hey, you are use value = '{{item}}' it should work

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: '{{ item }}' is not the answer.  The problem is with what is being put in the POST request, not what is displayed by the template.

Comment: Willie Cheng, I would be interested to know the reason why you are of that opinion, as my reading of the scope does not give me any cause for concern.